# Get User Account Active Directory Group in Windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, active-directory, winjs

I have been struggling with this problem all day.

I am developing a Windows 8 app using JavaScript and HTML5. I need to restrict some functionality on the app depending of the active directory group where an user account is assigned.

The question is: how I can check if a user account belongs to a Active Directory group?

I have tried using Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation and Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.CredentialPicker, but none of them returns either a way to test if a user account belongs to a group, or the group where the user account is assigned.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to perform this, which was the one I implemented, and it works. You can create a web service that validates the credentials against Active Directory, where you pass the domain, username and password, then call it from the app using WinJS.xhr. To ask for the credentials, you can use the CredentialPicker control, which returns, the domain, username, and password entered by the user.

Here is the code:

Web Service Code:

```
ValidateUserResult vur = new ValidateUserResult();

    try
    {
        using (PrincipalContext context =
            new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
        {
            vur.UserCredentialsAreValid = context
                .ValidateCredentials(username, password);

            if (vur.UserCredentialsAreValid)
            {
                vur.ProcessMessageText = "Ok";
                vur.ProcessMessageCode = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                vur.ProcessMessageText =
                    "Credenciales invalidas";
                vur.ProcessMessageCode = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        vur.UserCredentialsAreValid = false;
        vur.ProcessMessageText = ex.Message;
        vur.ProcessMessageCode = ex.HResult;
    }

    return vur;
```

Windows 8 App:

```
WinJS.xhr({
    type: "get"
    , url: {Web Service Url}
        + "/json/{Web Service Method Name}?domain="
        + domain + "&username=" + username
        + "&password=" + password
}).then(
    function (result) {
        if (result.status === 200) {

            // Place code here.

        }
    },
    function (error) {

        // If an error occurs, manage here

    });
```